# Baixando o HTML de uma página

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Gostaria de saber uma maneira ou plugin que me auxilie em baixar o HTML da página em formato .html. O meu objetivo é tornar possível editar imagens e textos em uma imagem e ao fim poder baixa-la. Eu tentei utilizar o download.js http://danml.com/download.html. Mas este, só me deixa baixar o body do HTML, obviamente seria minha intenção baixar todo o corpo, alternativamente, em PHP eu descobri esta página: https://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php. Onde aparamentemente os arquivos são baixados como .zip. Estou utilizando o wamp, mas não sei como rodar esta função para baixar os arquivos...

Eis aqui um exemplo da página eu eu preciso baixar

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ola mundo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Esta é uma página que pode ser baixada</p>
    <p>2019@</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a melhor resposta neste link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080943/download-php-generated-webpage-as-html-file

de longe a maneira mais elegante para baixar o HTML utilizando php.

```html
<?php

 //Link to download file...
 $url = "http://example.com/test.php";

 //Code to get the file...
 $data = file_get_contents($url);

 //save as?
 $filename = "test.html";

 //save the file...
 $fh = fopen($filename,"w");
 fwrite($fh,$data);
 fclose($fh);

 //display link to the file you just saved...
 echo "<a href='".$filename."'>Click Here</a> to download the file...";

?>
```